# Why does iTunes Smart Playlist dialog start with a checkbox?

Tags: gui-design, checkboxes

[image]

Unchecking the checkbox disables the logic argument builder and the OK button. I have a similar component I'm working on, and I for the life of me cannot suss out why Apple made "Match the following rule:" a checkbox. Please help!

Articles directly from Apple are preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has a checkbox because you can disable all the rules and choose songs by using the `selected by` part (*random*, *album*, *artist*, etc.).

[image]